# Determining where fopen() is writing files when used from WordPress AJAX call

Tags: plugins, php

I have a WordPress Plugin which uses AJAX to send mail. It works fine. Now I want to put a bit of code to write a log file when the mail is sent.

The parameter `$u` is simply a bit of text to be logged.

```
function writeToLog( $u ) {
    $path = 'log.txt';
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (($h = fopen($path, "a")) !== FALSE) {
        $mystring = $u . ' ' . $agent . PHP_EOL;
        echo('mystring seems to be working');
        fwrite( $h, $mystring );
        fclose($h);
    }
    else
      die('WHAT IS GOING ON?');
}
```

It appears as though `fopen()` is working, but I can't find the `log.txt` file. I *thought* it would be located in the same folder as the plugin. Where this `log.txt` file is being written? Do I need to provide an explicit `$path` to write this file within the plugin directory?

Comment: in the `/wp-admin`, probably, if the code is executed over admin or the root dir. You should provide full path like this `$path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'log.txt'`

Comment: Perfect. It was, indeed, in the /wp-admin. If I want to write to the root folder of the site, is there a built-in function for that?

Comment: `$path = ABSPATH . 'log.txt'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your CODE as is, where the `log.txt` file will be written depends on `PWD` (Present Working Directory value). It can be your web root, or any where else.

However, since WordPress AJAX calls are made to [`wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/#url) file, `PWD` for AJAX is almost always the `wp-admin/` directory. So if you use the file path as `$path = 'log.txt';`, the log file will almost always be created within the `wp-admin/` directory.

Now, to make sure it's created in your Plugin directory, you may use:

```
function writeToLog( $u ) {
    // this will create the log where the CODE of this function is
    // adjust it to write within the plugin directory
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt';
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (($h = fopen($path, "a")) !== FALSE) {
        $mystring = $u . ' ' . $agent . PHP_EOL;
        echo('mystring seems to be working');
        fwrite( $h, $mystring );
        fclose($h);
    }
    else
        die('WHAT IS GOING ON?');
}
```

Since it's WordPress (with default setup), you may use `ABSPATH` constant to write it in the `Web Root` as well:

```
$path = ABSPATH . 'log.txt';
```

> BTW, it's always better to write these sort of logs in your own plugin directory instead of `web root`. You better keep web root not writable by scripts (good for security).

Comment: Is there a preference between ABSPATH and get_home_path()?

Comment: `ABSPATH` will give you web root, on the other hand, the result of `get_home_path()` can be different based on the `home` option setting in `WP Admin`.